# How to make part titles visible in ConTeXt?

Tags: sectioning, context, parts, context-mkiv

ConTeXt has `\part`, `\chapter`, and `\section` titles, however, it seems that `\part` is disabled by default. If I used `\part` in my document, it is visible in the table of contents, but not in the document. I have tried setting it up myself, but this does not work:

```
\setuphead[part][number=no, align=middle]
```

- What is the basic code needed to display and begin setting up and customizing `\part` titles?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use:

```
\setuphead
  [part][placehead=yes]
```

The placement can be tuned using the standard `\setuphead` [keys](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuphead).